# Difference between `T&` and `const T&` for all-const class

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer

Suppose that I have a class like that:

```
class Foo : boost::noncopyable
{
public:
  Foo(int a, int b);

  const int something;
  const int something_else;
  const std::string another_field;
  // and that's that, no more methods nor fields
};
```

Now, is there any practical difference between accessing the objects of this class through a `Foo&`, as opposed to `const Foo&`, other than that these two are two distinct types?

There shouldn't be any difference for accessing its *fields*, as they're `const`, so they will be accessed to through a `const T&` anyway.

But is there *any* difference when it comes to the class as a whole? Something to do with templates, perhaps? Anything?

---

Now that [templatetypedef has written a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9266266/784668), which unfortunately is not helpful in this case, I think it'd be nice to underline that it's very much about *what can you do when you already have a reference* (note all these "accessing"), not about what you can bind to the reference.

So, you can assume that the ref is already there, bound to some object. Now it's all about what can be done with it.

Comment: On a side note, if you have two `Foo`s called `a` and `b`, the assignment `a = b` is illegal. Is that what you want?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes, it's even made explicit: `class Foo : boost::noncopyable`.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but consider this function:

```
void DoSomething(Foo& fooRef);
```

In this case, you *cannot* call

```
DoSomething(Foo()); // Error- can't bind a reference to a temporary
```

However, if we have this function:

```
void DoSomethingConst(const Foo& fooRef);
```

Then we can indeed call

```
DoSomethingConst(Foo()); // Okay - const reference can bind to a temporary
```

So there is a slightly difference in that a `const` reference can potentially bind to a temporary `Foo` when a non-`const` reference cannot.  Consequently, you'd probably want functions taking in `Foo`s to take in a `const Foo&` rather than a `Foo&` to make it possible to call the function with temporaries.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. Also aren't there some optimisations the compiler can do for `const` things?

Comment: @SethCarnegie I thought about that, but since all members are const, can't the optimizations happen anyway? +1 from me too.

Comment: Oh, although that's as obvious as right, it's more about what can be bound to the reference than about what can you do when accessing it. And I doubt I'll ever need to make a temporary of this type. So while I appreciate you answer, I can't honestly upvote it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: actually, `const` rarely helps with optimizations, compilers usually get much more accurate information from their own data flow analysis than from `const`s.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Actually, most of the optimizations are only valid if the system can determine that the object itself is `const`; accessing through a `const` reference doesn't help (but declaring `const` members might).

Comment: @JamesKanze: In fact, it's "...that the object itself does not change".

Comment: @Fanael A const object cannot change (unless it is also volatile).  The compiler knows this, even if its data flow analysis can't prove it.  So declaring an object const can help optimization.  An object referred to through a const reference can change, either through a different path, or by casting away const.  If I pass `Foo` to a function through a const reference, the compiler cannot assume that it is unchanged.  If `Foo` has const members, however, it can assume that they are unchanged.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah, a `const` object cannot change, but "the object itself does not change" is more general than "the object itself is `const`". And while it's true that the compiler knows that `const` objects don't change, it rarely makes any use of it during optimizations - typically all `const`s are lost when translating the IR on which the optimizations are done. Which is good if the IR is in SSA form, as everything is `const` there anyway.

Comment: @Fanael That doesn't correspond to what I've seen in compilers.  Most of the time, most compilers optimize one function at a time.  I you have a local `Foo`, and you call a function which has a `Foo const&` argument, the compiler must assume that non-const members have changed.  I the members are const, it knows they haven't.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'm referring to the part about `const` objects, not references to `const`.